# Why pyautogui's write() implements keys delay on its own

Tags: python, pyautogui

> I am sending keys via. pyautogui, this is my code :

```
pyautogui.write(df["description"].iloc[0])
```

> The `df["description"].iloc[0]` has HTML element which is being fetched from a CSV file , here it is :

```
    <div class="post-body entry-content" id="post-body-1273698268205185937">

<center>
  <style>
.sn_responsive_1 { width: 320px; height: 250px;}
@media(min-width:400px) {.sn_responsive_1 {width: 336px; height: 600px;}}
@media(min-width:1100px) {.sn_responsive_1 {width: 600px;height: 330px;}}
</style>
<center><!-- New-AC -->

<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></center>
<div id="PostBody">
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
</div>
<div style="text-align: justify;">
<span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b>APDCL, AEGCL</b> &amp; <b>APGCL.<br/>Last Date: 31/10/2018. </b></span></span></span></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b> </b></span></span></span></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><span style="font-size: medium;"><b><u>Update as on 12th November 2021</u>: It is for the information of all concerned that the recruitment process for the post of <u>OCFA, Sahayak and Driver(fresh)</u> category vide employment notice no MD/APDCL/HR/REC (2017-18)/2017/85/119 Dtd 10.08.2018 has been <u>cancelled</u> due to administrative reasons. Official order is <a href="https://www.apdcl.org/website/docs/career/Cancellation%20Notice_OCFA,%20Sahayak,%20Driver%20(Fresh%20Category)_12112021.pdf" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">here</a> .<br/></b></span></span></span></span></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><span style="font-size: medium;"><b>  <br/><div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEiZ96FiyhHBSoCoNRopVKADkFNnI16go15OivaxvvQjKW69_8pgP6kMnIii5dBUO5u57FurQ3xCBZDrQ9_zRAVX1i2cLmtiCHi0_XvhbYXeGe8JWCKhUMUNgP8lo75apqLQZT5fcyQz5738lK9FuFOLhmQzXjfyo5H1AXQoUPdNU_h_lV8gbduL9L2r=s1210" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"></a></div><br/></b><span><a name="more"></a></span></span></span></span></span><h3><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><span style="font-size: large;"><b>APDCL, AEGCL &amp; APGCL Recruitment 2018 </b></span></span></span></span></h3></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'> </span></span></span></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'>Applications are invited from candidates having requisite qualifications for appointment in &amp;<b> APGCL</b> in the following categories of posts as shown below via <u><b>EMPLOYMENT NOTICE NO.: MD/APDCL/HR/REC (2017-18)/2017/85/119</b></u>. <span style="background-color: yellow;">These posts need NO prior working experience</span> .<br/><br/></span></span></span><h3><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b><span style="font-size: large;">APDCL, AEGCL &amp; APGCL Recruitment Details</span></b></span></span></span></h3><h3><span style="font-family: arial;"></span></h3></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b> </b></span></span></span></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b>1. AAO (Assistant Accounts Officer)<br/>No of posts: </b><span style="background-color: yellow;">60</span> [APDCL: 35, APGCL: 10, AEGCL: 15]/ [UR: 28, OBC/MOBC: 16, 
STP: 7, SC: 4, STH: 4, PWD: 1]<br/><b><br/>Educational Qualification: </b>Bachelor Degree in Arts, Science or Commerce from a recognized University with minimum 55% marks or its equivalent in B.Com in aggregate or 55% marks in Honors/Major subject (B.Com) or minimum 55% aggregate marks or its equivalent for Arts or Science graduate having Mathematics or Statistics as one of the subjects or 55% marks or its equivalent in Mathematics/Statistics as Honors (BA/B.Sc.)<br/><br/>For departmental candidates (employees of APDCL/APGCL/AEGCL), and those belonging to the Scheduled Caste/ Scheduled Tribe minimum qualifying marks in bachelor degree is 50 %.<br/><b><br/>Computer Proficiency: </b>A candidate must possess proficiency in computer application and 
having diploma certificate in computer application with minimum duration of 3 (three) months.<br/><br/><b>Age :</b><br/>a. 21 to 44 years as on 01.01.2018.<br/>b. In case of OBC/MOBC candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 47 years.<br/>c. In case of SC/ST candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 49 years.<br/>d. In case of departmental candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 45 years.<br/><br/><b>Pay: </b>16,800 – 60,500/- , GP: 8,700/-<br/><b><br/>2. Office cum Field Assistant<br/>No of posts:</b> <span style="background-color: yellow;">1000 </span>[APDCL: 968, APGCL: 11, AEGCL: 21]/ 
[UR: 340, OBC/MOBC: 272, STP: 146, SC: 107, STH: 91, PWD: 44]<br/><br/><b>Educational Qualification:</b> Minimal HSSLC or equivalent examination recognized by Govt.<br/><b><br/>Computer Proficiency:</b> A candidate must possess proficiency in computer application and having diploma certificate in computer application with minimum duration of 3 (three) months.<br/><br/><b>Age :</b><br/>a. 18 to 44 years as on 01.01.2018.<br/>b. In case of OBC/MOBC candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 47 years.<br/>c. In case of SC/ST candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 49 years.<br/>d. In case of departmental candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 45 years.<br/><b><br/>Pay: </b>16,800 – 60,500/- , GP: 5,800/<br/><b><br/>3. Light Vehicle Driver<br/>No of posts:</b> <span style="background-color: yellow;">25</span> [APDCL: 25]/ [UR: 12, OBC/MOBC: 7, STP: 3, SC: 2, STH: 1]<br/><b><br/>Educational Qualification:</b> HSLC or equivalent examination recognized by Govt., must have at least 2 (two) years professional driving licence and must be proficient in traffic rules &amp; driving LMV/HMV.<br/><b><br/>Age :</b><br/>a. 18 to 44 years as on 01.01.2018.<br/>b. In case of OBC/MOBC candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 47 years.<br/>c. In case of SC/ST candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 49 years.<br/>d. In case of departmental candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 45 years.<br/><br/><b>Pay:</b> 12,400 – 47,400/-, GP: 5,500/<br/><br/><b>4. Sahayak<br/>No of posts: </b><span style="background-color: yellow;">872</span> [APDCL: 620, APGCL: 52, AEGCL: 200]/ [UR: 231, OBC/MOBC: 234, STP: 180, SC: 120, STH: 107]<br/><br/><b>Educational Qualification: </b><br/>a. For APDCL: HSLC or equivalent with ITI in the trade of Wireman/Electrician from Govt. of Assam approved Institute.<br/>b. For AEGCL: HSLC or equivalent with ITI in the trade of Electrician/Fitter from Govt. of Assam approved Institute.<br/>c. For APGCL: HSLC or equivalent with ITI in the trade of Wireman/Electrician/ Fitter/Welder/Machinist, from Govt. of Assam approved Institute.<br/><b><br/>Age :</b><br/>a. 18 to 44 years as on 01.01.2018.<br/>b. In case of OBC/MOBC candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 47 years.<br/>c. In case of SC/ST candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 49 years.<br/>d. In case of departmental candidates, upper age limit is relaxed upto 45 years.<br/><br/><b>Pay: </b>12,400 – 47,400/-, GP: 4,500/<br/><br/><b>Note: </b><span style="background-color: yellow;">The candidate must be a citizen of India and domicile of Assam.</span> Candidate having adequate knowledge in communicating in Assamese and/or local languages will be preferred. Candidates have to submit documents in proof of domicile at the time of Document verification/Physical Efficiency Test, if called for.<br/><b><br/>Application Fee (Non Refundable):</b> <strike>Rs. 500.00 (Rupees Five Hundred only) for General/OBC/MOBC candidates and Rs. 250.00 (Rupees Two Hundred Fifty only) for SC/ST candidates. Application fees are exempted for PWD candidates. Candidate has to pay the application fee through online mode only by using Net Banking/Credit Card/Debit Card.</strike></span></span><br/></span>
<span style="font-family: arial;"><br/></span>
<span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'>For General/OBC/MOBC Candidates: Rs. 
100<br/>For SC/ST Candidates: Rs. 50 </span></span><br/></span>
<span style="font-family: arial;"><br/></span>
<span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'>Sometimes due to <i><b>broken transaction at recruiter's end</b></i>, the amount paid by the candidate does not gets updated in the database immediately. Please check <i><b>after 3 (three) working days</b></i> from the <b>date of payment</b> and the payment receipt will be available in the candidate's portal.<br/><br/>In case of multiple payment against same Registration No., the extra amount will be refunded to the account from where it has been deducted. <i><b>But, the refund process may take some time after the last date of online application process</b></i>. <br/><b><br/></b></span></span></span><h3><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b><span style="font-size: large;">Selection Procedure of APDCL, AEGCL &amp; APGCL Recruitment</span></b></span></span></span></h3><h3><span style="font-family: arial;"></span></h3><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><br/>The candidates will have to appear in the written test to be notified in due course. The written test for all the posts mentioned above may be conducted on the same date. The written test shall contain 1 (one) paper of 100 marks as indicated below. The candidates selected through written test will be called for Document Verification for the post of AAO (Assistant Accounts Officer), Office cum Field Assistant and Document verification / Physical Efficiency Test for the post of Sahayak. The final selection list will be prepared based on the marks obtained in the written test only. No TA or DA will be admissible for the journey in connection with written test/ Physical Efficiency Test. The decision of the Selection Board/ Committee for the eligibility or otherwise of a candidate for admissible in the written test shall be final. Inclusion of a candidate's name in the final selection list will not confer him/her the right for appointment, unless the appointing authority is satisfied that the candidate is suitable for appointment in all respects.<br/><br/>Candidates for the post of Sahayak who fails to qualify in 
the Physical Efficiency Test, will not be considered for final appointment.<br/><br/>In case of Light Vehicle Driver the candidates have to appear for 
a practical test in addition to a written examination which would be notified in due course.<br/><b><br/></b></span></span></span><h3><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b><span style="font-size: large;">How to Apply for APDCL, AEGCL &amp; APGCL Recruitment ?</span></b></span></span></span></h3></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b> </b></span></span></span></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span 
style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'>Eligible and interested candidates are required to apply through online mode only in the “Career” section of APDCL website i.e., <i><b>www.apdcl.org</b></i>. No other means/mode of application shall be accepted. <span style="background-color: yellow;">Online submission of the applications will be available on the website between <strike>18.08.2018</strike> <strike>01.09.2018</strike> <strike><i>25.08.2018</i></strike> <b>01.10.2018</b> to <strike>12.09.2018</strike> <i><strike>25.09.2018</strike> <strike>19.09.2018</strike></i> <b>31.10.2018</b>.</span></span></span><br/></span>
<span style="font-family: arial;"><br/></span>
<span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><span style="background-color: yellow;"><b>Online Application for Class - III &amp; IV posts (Fresh &amp; Experienced Categories) will be closed w.e.f 13.09.2018 to 30.09.2018 and shall be re-opened w.e.f 01.10.2018 to 31.10.2018 due to Technical Maintenance.  </b></span></span></span></span></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><span 
style="background-color: white;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b> </b></span></span></span></span></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><h3><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span face='"arial" , "helvetica" , sans-serif'><b><span></span><span style="font-size: large;">Important Web-Links of APDCL Recruitment</span></b></span><br/></span></span></h3></div></div><div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on"><br/><table class="tablepress tablepress-id-45"><tbody class="row-hover"><tr class="row-1 odd"><td class="column-1"><span style="font-size: small;"><b><span><span><span><span><span style="font-family: arial;"><span>Online Application Form<br/></span></span></span></span></span></span></b></span></td><td class="column-2"><span style="font-size: small;"><b><span><span><span><span><span style="font-family: arial;"><span><a href="https://www.apdcl.net.in/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Click Here</a><br/></span></span></span></span></span></span></b></span></td></tr><tr class="row-2 even"><td class="column-1"><span style="font-size: small;"><b><span><span><span><span><span style="font-family: arial;"><span>Advertisement Details<br/></span></span></span></span></span></span></b></span></td><td class="column-2"><span style="font-size: small;"><b><span><span><span><span><span style="font-family: arial;"><span><a href="https://www.apdcl.org/irj/go/km/docs/internet/ASSAM/webpage/PDF/20180814_Class_III_IV_Fresh_2018.pdf" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Link I</a> | <a href="https://www.apdcl.org/irj/go/km/docs/internet/ASSAM/webpage/PDF/20180814_Class_III_IV_Instructions.pdf" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Link II</a><br/></span></span></span></span></span></span></b></span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><span style="font-family: arial;">
</span>
</div>
<div id="AdCode">
<div style="margin:5px 0;text-align:center;clear:both;">
<center>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></center>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</center></div>
```

> Why the delay is introduced after each word being typed ? How can I elimiate the delay ?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a 0 second pause after each PyAutoGUI call:

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
```

Our you can add the "interval" keyword argument to the write function.

```
pyautogui.write('Hello world!', interval=0.25)  # prints out "Hello world!" with a quarter second delay after each character
```